# Spring Boot How to run multiple method with @Scheduled

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a Spring Boot app where I want to have multiple methods to run at different times of the day. The first one runs, but no subsequent method runs. What do I need to do to fix this?
Here is my code:

```java
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
//@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.enable.scheduling")
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value = "prop.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class Application {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static MyClass class = new MyClass();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        InputStream resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("log4j2.properties");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(resourceAsStream);

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${4am.cron.expression}", zone = "America/New_York") //0 0 6 * * ?
    public void method1() {
         something;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${10am.cron.expression}", zone = "America/New_York") //0 0 6 * * ?
    public void method2() {
         something;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${10am.cron.expression}", zone = "America/New_York") //0 0 6 * * ?
    public void method3() {
         something;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${330pm.cron.expression}", zone = "America/New_York") //0 0 6 * * ?
    public void method4() {
         something;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${430pm.cron.expression}", zone = "America/New_York") //0 0 6 * * ?
    public void stopExecutor() {
        MyClass class = new MyClass();
        Executor executor = new Executor(class);
        executor.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the scheduled methods in a separate `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Sorry.  That doesn't work. Do I put each in their separate class or all together in one class?  I have them all in one class and only the first one is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try annonate method you are trying to run at given scheduled day / time using @Scheduled ( cron = "your cron job time ") on method.

E.g.

```
@Scheduled(cron = " specify cron job here ")
public void run job() { 
      // Code here
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Oh yes, I did not see that sorry. Can you put your all three @Scheduled methods in separate configuration class and see if that works.

Comment: I think that did it.  I will verify tomorrow when the real run occurs.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The real issue was gradle and Intellij.  There was something weird that was causing this issue.  I went to Maven and this has been resolved.  I can put 3 or more @Scheduled and they all run.